# Call stored procedure postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

How is possible to call a stored procedure in postgres with php?

I'm trying this but don't work

```
$result= pg_query($conect, SELECT name_function());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result= pg_query($conect, "SELECT name_function();");
```

you need pass a string into query..